# When does useEffect call when I use it with useContext?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, use-effect, use-context

I call useEffect inside useContext and I want to know when this useEffect is called.

**[settingContext.tsx]**

```
// create context object
export const ColorContext = createContext<ColorContextType>(null);

export const ProductsProvider = (props) => {
  const { query } = useRouter();

  const [data, setData] = useState<ColorContextType>(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchAPI() {
      const res = await fetch(`${env.API_URL_FOR_CLIENT}/page_settings/top`);
      const posts = await res.json();
      setData(posts);
    }
    fetchAPI();
  }, []);
  return <ColorContext.Provider value={data}>{props.children}</ColorContext.Provider>;
};

export const useColorContext = () => {
  const colors = useContext(ColorContext);
  let themeColor: string = '';
  let titleColor: string = '';

  if (colors !== null) {
    const colorData = colors.response.result_list[3].value;
    themeColor = JSON.parse(colorData).theme_color;
    titleColor = JSON.parse(colorData).title_color;
  }
  return { themeColor, titleColor };
};
```

**[_app.tsx]**

```
export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <LayoutInitial>
      <ProductsProvider>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </ProductsProvider>
    </LayoutInitial>
  );
}
```

I use `useColorContext` on multiple components.
It seems like useEffect is only called on `'/'` page, which is fine but I'm curious that useEffect should be called every time pages are rendered but it seems that it doesn't.
is this because I use useContext?

Answer (score 0):

The `useEffect` call is done in the `ProductsProvider` component which appears to only be rendered once, on page load/refresh. This is because components generally only re-render when a state they subscribe to is changed. If the `useEffect` were called directly within the `<Component>` component, it would be called every time the component is mounted (not in re-renders). `useEffect` is only called multiple times after mounting if one of its dependencies changes, which in your case, there are none.

For example: this sandbox

[image: Edit lucid-jepsen-zwdfyv]

It's composed of the `App` component, containing a `Router` to a homepage, a `ComponentA` route, and a `ComponentB` route. When each component mounts, its `useEffect` is called, creating an alert box. You'll only see the `App` `useEffect` alert once per page refresh.

`ComponentA` will have its `useEffect` called when the component mounts (every time you hit the `/a` route from a different route), and when the `state` in the component changes, since it's in the `useEffect` dependency array.

ComponentB will only have its `useEffect` called when the component mounts, and not when its state changes, because the state isn't included in the `useEffect` dependency array.

EDIT: To clarify, your `useColorContext` hook is not actually part of the ProductsProvider component, so the `useEffect` call is not "inherited" by any components that call the hook. Also, keep in mind when experimenting that using `Strict Mode` will cause components to render twice, allowing react to gather information on the first render, and display it on the second render.